# How to add custom field to page multilineitem.jsp for opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem

Is there a way to add custom field to the page multilineitem.jsp for opportunity? (URL salesforce.com/oppitm/multilineitem.jsp)

Here is page screen:
[image: multilineitem.jsp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - From Setup,  click Customize | Opportunities | Opportunity Products |    Page Layouts.
> - Next to the name of an opportunity product page layout, click Edit.     Click Edit Multi-Line Layout.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=layouts_opp_product_multiline.htm